# Inside my directive a scope.$apply(function () getting called in Angular 1.2.2 but not Angular 1.2.7

Tags: angularjs

I have the following directive:

```
app.directive('pagedownAdmin', function ($compile) {
    var nextId = 0;
    var markdownConverter = new Markdown.Converter();
    var converter1 = Markdown.getSanitizingConverter();

    converter1.hooks.chain("preBlockGamut", function (text, rbg) {
        return text.replace(/^ {0,3}""" *\n((?:.*?\n)+?) {0,3}""" *$/gm, function (whole, inner) {
            return "<blockquote>" + rbg(inner) + "</blockquote>\n";
        });
    });

    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            modal: '=modal',
            ngModel: '=',
            pid: '=pid'
        },
        template: '<div class="pagedown-bootstrap-editor"></div>',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

            var editorUniqueId;

            if (attrs.id == null) {
                editorUniqueId = nextId++;
            } else {
                editorUniqueId = attrs.id;
            }

            var template = '<div>' +
            '<div class="wmd-panel">' +
            '<div data-ng-hide="modal.wmdPreview == true" id="wmd-button-bar-' + editorUniqueId + '"></div>' +
            '<textarea data-ng-hide="modal.wmdPreview == true" class="wmd-input" id="wmd-input-' + editorUniqueId + '">' +
            '</textarea>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div data-ng-show="modal.wmdPreview == true" id="wmd-preview-' + editorUniqueId + '" class="pagedown-preview wmd-panel wmd-preview">test div</div>' +
            '</div>';

            element.html($compile(template)(scope));

            var converter = new Markdown.Converter();

            var help = function () {
                var rawContent = $wmdInput.val();
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(rawContent);
                });
            }

            var editor = new Markdown.Editor(converter1, "-" + editorUniqueId, {
                handler: help
            });

            editor.run();

            var $wmdInput = $("#wmd-input-" + editorUniqueId);

            $wmdInput.on('keyup', _.debounce(function () {
                rawContent = $wmdInput.val();          // LINE 1
                scope.$apply(function () {             
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(rawContent); // LINE 2
                });
            }, 500));

        }
    }
});
```

There are two ways I use this directive:

1. Directly inside my HTML
2. Inside a ng-repeat

Here's what happens with the two versions of Angular

- With version 1.2.2 of Angular inside the HTML and inside the
  ng-repeat it goes to LINE1 and LINE2
- With version 1.2.7 of Angular inside the HTML it goes to LINE1 and LINE2
- With version 1.2.7 of
  Angular inside the HTML it goes to LINE1

Can someone give me some advice on why this is. I have had to return my code to 1.2.2 to get it to work again.

**Update**

I simplified the code for testing to:

```
        $wmdInput.on('keyup', function () {
            console.log("Before change: ngModel.$modelValue:" + ngModel.$modelValue);
            console.log("Before change: ngModel.$viewlValue:" + ngModel.$viewlValue);
            var rawContent = $wmdInput.val();
            ngModel.$setViewValue(rawContent);
            console.log("After change: ngModel.$modelValue:" + ngModel.$modelValue);
            console.log("After change: ngModel.$viewlValue:" + ngModel.$viewlValue);
        });
```

I first entered a letter "q" and then a letter "x" with version 1.2.3:

```
efore change: ngModel.$modelValue:zzx pagedownAdmin.js:68
Before change: ngModel.$viewlValue:undefined pagedownAdmin.js:69
After change: ngModel.$modelValue:q pagedownAdmin.js:72
After change: ngModel.$viewlValue:undefined pagedownAdmin.js:73
Before change: ngModel.$modelValue:zzx pagedownAdmin.js:68
Before change: ngModel.$viewlValue:undefined pagedownAdmin.js:69
After change: ngModel.$modelValue:x pagedownAdmin.js:72
After change: ngModel.$viewlValue:undefined pagedownAdmin.js:73
```

It seems that every time the ngModel is set but then next time it goes into the key handler the value is the original value.

Comment: It would be nice if you checked if it works on greater versions than 1.2.2 so we know which version break your code

Comment: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.min.js
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.3/angular.min.js

Comment: I will start checking with each now. Thanks

Comment: 1.2.3 Goes to LINE2 but it seems not to save anything. When I check with Fiddler the data going back to the server is not match rawContent. It's the same as the original data. If I make a change it sets the ngModel correctly inside of the { } but next time I make another change and look ngModel is still at the original value.

Comment: angular.js 1.2.3: `There are no breaking changes in this release (promise!)`  ?!

Comment: Why do you need all those scope hooks? modal ? ngModel ? pid?

Comment: If you can put more code (plunker?) maybe I could reproduce that same bug.

Comment: http://cssdeck.com/labs/ppmpabhk
I cannot reproduce your bug

Comment: You can delete this post now