# Do I need to use a scope.$apply inside a directive when setting the model value?

Tags: angularjs

This is related to a [question I asked earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949645/inside-my-directive-a-scope-applyfunction-getting-called-in-angular-1-2-2-b).

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {

            $wmdInput.on('keyup', _.debounce(function () {
                rawContent = $wmdInput.val();          // LINE 1
                scope.$apply(function () {             
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(rawContent); // LINE 2
                });
            }, 500));
```

Inside the link portion of a directive. Is it necessary to set the model value inside a

```
scope.$apply( function ()
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I  think that in your case you need invoke `$apply`.  `$scope.$apply()` calls `$scope.$digest()`. The `$digest` loops through all watchers on the specific scope

From [DOCS](http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.5/docs/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController#methods_%24setviewvalue):

> Note that calling `$setViewValue(value)` function does not trigger a $digest.

Comment: thanks by the way did you see my previous question about directives and the apply call working in 1.2.2 but not in 1.2.7 ?  This is related.  It's good if I don't need it as it seems to no longer work in the latest version.

Comment: No, I don't  see previous one

Comment: Here's the previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20949645/inside-my-directive-a-scope-applyfunction-getting-called-in-angular-1-2-2-b